# First 500gram 38 dollars, subsequent 500gram 12 dollars

Tags: excel, formulas

I have a problem with the formulas.
I was trying to create a formula that auto calculates first 500grams 38 dollars, subsequent 500grams 12 dollars. Like a courier parcels weighing cost.

I tried the below, but end up an error with too many arguments: -

`=IF(I20>=5,SUM(38,(12*9))), IF(I20>=4.5,SUM(38,(12*8))),IF(I20>=4.0,SUM(38,(12*7))), IF(I20>=3.5,SUM(38,(12*6))), IF(I20>=3,SUM(38,(12*5))), IF(I20>=2.5,SUM(38,(12*4))), IF(I20>=2,SUM(38,(12*3))), IF(I20>=1.5,SUM(38,(12*2))), IF(I20>=1,SUM(38,(12*1))), IF(I20>=0.5,SUM(38,(12*0)))`

Any taker pls?

Comment: Ummmmm Where exactly?

Comment: Is this Excel? If so, please add that as a tag. If not, please add whatever language you *are* working in as a tag.

Comment: Also, a different way to think about this is probably that the price is 12 dollars per 500gram, plus 26 dollars - that may make your problem easier to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A1<=500,38,(ROUNDUP((A1/500),0)-1)*12+38)
```

try this assuming you are using excel

Comment: Can you accept the answer as well. so others will know it's good one!! :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this....

```
 public int getprice(double quantity)
{
int x = Math.cieling(quantity/0.5);
double price = 38 + (x-1)*12;
return price;
}
```

this method will return you price.